# Why am I getting weird and unpredictable behaviour from substrings in bash?

Tags: string, bash, command-line, scripting

I am making a bash script. I first grab a line with grep from a realtime updating output (top, airodump-ng) then I am trying to parse that line and extract certain substrings. My problem is the ${VAR:start:length} syntax does not work and is unpredictable. I will show some examples,

My original unparsed string is this, I am trying to extract the two Mac addresses (which I made up)

```
VAR="12:34:56:78:91:23 23:45:67:89:12:34 -37 24e-24e 0 23"
```

In the script, var is defined by  `VAR="airodump-ng | grep ...`  but for this post it is a string literal.

So maybe there is some random whitespace characters messing with it from grep. Anyways, when I try to take substrings of VAR this is what happens,

```
SUB=${VAR:1:25}
12:34:56:78:91:23 23:45:
```

Good

```
SUB${VAR:1:24}
12:34:56:78:91:23 23:45
```

Good

```
SUB${VAR:1:23}
12:34:56:78:91:
```

Bad

You can see now out of nowhere the substring is much shorter than expected, going from 24->23 does not make it one character shorter but 9 shorter. This patter continues, for example, 12, 13, 14 work but 15 is way to short again. The same thing happens with the cut command `echo $VAR | cut -c1-25` with the same indexes.

So how can I fix this and why is it happening. Or are there any better solutions to extract these substrings?

```
                                        .
```

Comment: How do you assign and print the substring? You show what I think are assignments with a missing `=`, and then the content of the variable, but how do you generate that string?

Comment: I do ```SUB=${VAR:1:23}``` then just ```echo $SUB```, but I intend to use SUB as an argument to future commands in the bash script as in ```CMD $SUB $SUB2 ...``` @BenjaminW.

Comment: If you run `declare -p VAR` on your original variable and then with `declare -p SUB`, do you see any unexpected characters? Also, beware: [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29378566/3266847)

Comment: Also, your outputs don't seem right even for the good cases; `${VAR:1:...}` should cut off the first character.

Comment: Thats also part of the problem, the first characters seem to constantly change. I ran this for loop, ```for ((i = 0; i<${#RAW}; i++)); do
    echo "$i ------ ${RAW:0:$i}"
done```

and this is the first few lines,

```0 ------ 
1 ------ 
 ------ 


5 ------ 
 ------ 


9 ------  
10 ------  2
11 ------  24
12 ------  24:```

Additionally it changes, sometimes it will correctly format and sometimes it does not. I tried running it in a new shell to clear any stdout, "bash -c "..."" but it normally works the first time then stops. @BenjaminW.

Comment: Does not seem to print out any weird characters. Also I looked at that post but could not connect any dots. @BenjaminW. Additionally my initial string is obtained with this in my bash script, ```RAW=$(airodump-ng wlan0 --essid MYSSID -a 2>&1 | grep -m 1 D0:23:54)``` I know this may be a lot to ask for but is there any way you could try to run this script and extract the MACS? I think all these string problems are happening because airodump-ng does not print line by line but updates the output realtime like the command ```top```. Also thank you for your help so far. Im a newbie and need it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have some weird/nonprinting characters in the variable. Try printing it with `printf '%s\n' "$RAW" | LC_ALL=C cat -vt` to convert normally-invisible things to visible representations.

Comment: Yep... I get ```^[[0K^[[1B ``` and sometimes shorter versions of it like just ```^[[0K``` its different every time. This seems to be where the varying length issue comes from.  @GordonDavisson Now to get rid of them ...